# NSJSONSerialization - modify an object into a json file

Tags: objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

I have this simple json file in my iphone/ipad project.

```
{"initial_page" : Page_Selected}
```

`Page_Selected` is an `NSInteger`

I want to modify through a `UIPickerView` the value of the `"initial_page"`. How to do that?

of course I've already done the `UiPickerWiew` selection part and about the json modification, I will write it into the

`-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponents:(NSInteger)component{ }`

function.

Maybe function that does the job is `[[jsonParsed setInteger:row forKey:@"initial_page"]` but this way, the debugger returns me "unrecognized selector sent" exception.

I need only the part in which to modify the `json` parameter with `"initial_page"` as the key.

anyone can help me?

---

that's what I got.

```
NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Config" ofType:@"json"];
NSMutableDictionary *configJson = [NSJSONSerialization
                JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]
                options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonParsingError];

[configJson setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:row] forKey:@"initial_page"];

NSLog(@"%@",jsonParsingError);
```

the last line returns me `(null)`, so the json file is ok.

BUT, If I print out `[configJson objectForKey:@"inital_page"]` then I can see it changes... so, is there a kind of "commit" or "save" command in order to make it persistent?

---

following suggestions:

```
NSData * modified = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:configJson options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonParsingError];

[modified writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&jsonParsingError];
NSLog(@"returned error: %@", [jsonParsingError localizedDescription]);
```

again, last line returns me `(null)` but I can't find any modification in the file

---

after changes, I can save the modification of the `initial_page`, but this works only on `iPhone/iPad Simulator` and not on the real device debugging.

here's what I do:

```
if([modified wirteToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingFileProtectionNone error:&jsonParsingError])
   NSLog(@"writing ok")
else
   NSLog(@"not ok with error :%@",jsonParsinError);
```

`Iphone simulator` has no problem with the last 4 lines, but when I run it on physical `iPhone`, the last `NSLog` gives:

```
"not ok with error : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 The Operation Could not be completed. Operation not permitted"
```

it seems a permission denied in writing the json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is solved: the main wrong concept is to write and / or modify files in the main bundle. now I do this in the `NSDocumentDirectory`

this way, I get no error and I can read/write the data directly in/from the iPhone.

I followed this guide: [link](http://www.developerfeed.com/ios/tutorial/copy-pdf-files-main-bundle-document-folder-ios) of course I use json as filter instead pdf.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should make your json valid by specifying initial value of `Page_Selected` as a number, otherwise you won't be able to parse it. For example `{"initial_page" : -1}` so you know for sure that it's an invalid initial value and you won't use it by accident

Then when parsing, specify `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` as an option for `+JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` method

Then you can actually modify obtained instance of `NSMutableDictionary`:

```
[jsonDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:row] forKey:@"initial_page"]
```

Comment: it does not actually persist file down to the disk, probably you want to serialize dictionary back to JSON `NSData` and use one of `writeToFile:` or `writeToURL:` methods

Answer (score 0):

> is there a kind of "commit" or "save" command in order to make it persistent?

You need to write the JSON back to a file.

Use NSJSONSerialization's [-dataWithJSONObject:options:error:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010946-CH1-SW4) method to create an NSData and then write that to a file.  Note that, you shouldn't attempt to write to resources in the app bundle.

Comment: I know, the best solution for that is sql lite database, but why "you shouldn't attempt to write to resources in the app bundle"?

Answer (score 0):

to put `NSDataWritingFileProtectionNone` as the `option` in the `dataWithJSONObject` function.now it works for me only on the simulator.